# asp.net dynamic GridView with dropdownlist column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to create a GridView with a DropDownList column dynamically/Programmatically?

My intent is, I shall only add a bare GridView on the aspx page (I wouldn't even add ItemTemplate in design-time). All of the other things, creation of the control to population of data, would be done in the code behind.

Any known web link?

Comment: Try the following links: [http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/169_DropDownList_Inside_GridView__Method_1_.aspx](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/169_DropDownList_Inside_GridView__Method_1_.aspx) [http://www.dotnet-friends.com/Articles/CSharp/ARTinCS69f533c9-2ebb-4a3e-96b9-ad0c49763e92.aspx](http://www.dotnet-friends.com/Articles/CSharp/ARTinCS69f533c9-2ebb-4a3e-96b9-ad0c49763e92.aspx) [http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/dropdownlist-gridview-csharp.aspx](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/dropdownlist-gridview-csharp.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the RowDataBound event and populate the correct information there.

Comment: Thanks to me, I found this, [ http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/7/10028537/how-to-add-template-colum.aspx ]